# ANTLR4 - parse function-like structures in regular text

Tags: parsing, antlr4, context-free-grammar

I'm experimenting with a grammar, which will be able to match function-like structures inside regular text. These functions starts with a dollar sign accept text arguments surrounded by apostrophes and allows nesting of other functions.

I was able to achieve this with more constrained conditions like every text has to be surrounded by apostrophes and concatenation with '+' character is available but I wanted to redesign it to work without this constraing.

I came up with this grammar:

```
grammar Functions;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment LETTER : [A-Za-z];

FUNCTION_NAME : '$' LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)+;

APOSTROPHE : '\'';
LEFT_PARENTHESIS  : '(';
RIGHT_PARENTHESIS : ')';

ESCAPE_CHARACTER: '\\' [$()\\'];
TEXT  : '\'' ~[\r\n']* '\'';

PLAIN_TEXT : . -> skip;

start : subString*;

subString: function
   | ESCAPE_CHARACTER
   | LEFT_PARENTHESIS 
   | RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
   | APOSTROPHE
   | TEXT
   ;

function
    : FUNCTION_NAME LEFT_PARENTHESIS param? RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
    ;

param
    : function
    | TEXT
    ;
```

But following example does not work well:

```
Text $func('A') 'text $func2()'
```

Because `'text $func2()'` is matched as `TEXT` token. Therefore I came with escaping feature so adding `\'` solves the problem.

However, I'd like to make it work so that characters outside the function context are treated as regular characters. Because of this 'context' I'm starting to think that I've reached the limitations of **context-free** grammar but I don't have much practical experience to confirm that.

Is it possible to reach my requirements using ANTLR4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work:

#### FunctionsLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar FunctionsLexer;

FUNCTION_NAME : '$' LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* -> pushMode(InFunction);
PLAIN_TEXT : . -> skip;

mode InFunction;

FUNCTION_NAME_NESTED
 : '$' LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* -> type(FUNCTION_NAME), pushMode(InFunction)
 ;

PARAM : '\'' ~['$]* '\'';
LEFT_PARENTHESIS  : '(';
RIGHT_PARENTHESIS : ')' -> popMode;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment LETTER : [A-Za-z];
```

#### FunctionsParser.g4

```
parser grammar FunctionsParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=FunctionsLexer;
}

start
 : subString* EOF
 ;

subString
 : function
 ;

function
 : FUNCTION_NAME LEFT_PARENTHESIS param? RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
 ;

param
 : function
 | PARAM
 ;
```

The input `Text $func('A') 'text $func2()' BLA $fun3($fun4('...'))` produces 15 tokens:

```
  1    FUNCTION_NAME                  '$func'
  2    LEFT_PARENTHESIS               '('
  3    PARAM                          '\'A\''
  4    RIGHT_PARENTHESIS              ')'
  5    FUNCTION_NAME                  '$func2'
  6    LEFT_PARENTHESIS               '('
  7    RIGHT_PARENTHESIS              ')'
  8    FUNCTION_NAME                  '$fun3'
  9    LEFT_PARENTHESIS               '('
  10   FUNCTION_NAME                  '$fun4'
  11   LEFT_PARENTHESIS               '('
  12   PARAM                          '\'...\''
  13   RIGHT_PARENTHESIS              ')'
  14   RIGHT_PARENTHESIS              ')'
  15   EOF                            '<EOF>'
```

and `start` produces the following parse tree:

```
'- start
   |- subString
   |  '- function
   |     |- '$func' (FUNCTION_NAME)
   |     |- '(' (LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
   |     |- param
   |     |  '- '\'A\'' (PARAM)
   |     '- ')' (RIGHT_PARENTHESIS)
   |- subString
   |  '- function
   |     |- '$func2' (FUNCTION_NAME)
   |     |- '(' (LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
   |     '- ')' (RIGHT_PARENTHESIS)
   |- subString
   |  '- function
   |     |- '$fun3' (FUNCTION_NAME)
   |     |- '(' (LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
   |     |- param
   |     |  '- function
   |     |     |- '$fun4' (FUNCTION_NAME)
   |     |     |- '(' (LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
   |     |     |- param
   |     |     |  '- '\'...\'' (PARAM)
   |     |     '- ')' (RIGHT_PARENTHESIS)
   |     '- ')' (RIGHT_PARENTHESIS)
   '- '<EOF>'
```

Comment: Indeed, that's a good solution! I also put together an example, practically identical to yours, but... you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the solution I came up with after Olivier's hint with lexer modes. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Sorry about that @OctavianTheodor ;) Pretty darn quick to have found it yourself @Harry, given you were just introduced to the `mode` feature. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

I think your grammar can be simplified, as you only need to match "function calls" and don't care about anything else.

Here's a simpler version. I think it matches your basic requirements (functions with, at most, one argument, which can be a function call or a quoted string).

```
grammar Functions;

start
    : function*
    ;

function
    : FUNCTION_NAME LEFT_PARENTHESIS param? RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
    ;

param
    : PARAM
    | function
    ;

FUNCTION_NAME : '$' LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment LETTER : [A-Za-z];

PARAM
    : '\'' ~['$]* '\''
    ;

LEFT_PARENTHESIS  : '(';
RIGHT_PARENTHESIS : ')';

PLAIN_TEXT : . -> skip;
```

The main trick was to break out of a quoted string argument/param token via either the first encountered quote OR the first begin-function char, $.

Comment: I have tested this grammar and yes it works much better because it drops all text, which is not a function. But not in all cases. It fails when the plain text contains parentheses like here `($func()`. I was trying to handle it myself but without success. Additionally I tried to extend this grammar with sam additional features and every new symbol I'm introducing (like comma for multiple parameters) causes exactly the same problem. Presence of this symbol outside function causes everything after that symbol is not parsed.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. As soon as we introduce a (new) character/token in our lexer grammar, we need to make the distinction whether the token is in a plain text context or in a function-matching context. I believe we can achieve that with lexer modes; see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md. I'll have a try at that.

Comment: Thank you very much Octavian! I wasn't aware of that feature. I have created new mode and I'm entering into it when function is found and escape from when right parenthesis is found.

Comment: Alright, I'm glad to hear I could be of help.